# Why does a numpy array have 96 bytes of overhead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-internals, internals

If I take a simply and empty numpy array i can see it has 96 bytes of overhead,

```
>>> sys.getsizeof( np.array([]) )
96
```

What is that 96 bytes storing? Where in the C source for numpy or Python 3 (cpython) is this set up?

Comment: *All* objects have overhead; they aren't primitive values. They store things like reference counts, references to their type, pointers to the memory storing the actual data, etc.

Comment: @chepner I understand that. I even used the term "overhead". The question is what the overhead is here in this case. 96 bytes is 16, 64bit ints. With a regular python object, I believe there is one 64bit unsigned int for ref counting, and one for typing. What are the other 14 and where can I find them in the source? Where is the struct that lays out a numpy array?

Comment: It would be in the Numpy source code. Stack Overflow is not the appropriate place to ask for a pointer to that source code.

Comment: In my Python 3.6.10, `sys.getsizeof(int())` is 24, `sys.getsizeof(list())` 64 and, for an empty class `A`, `sys.getsizeof(A())` is 56. Assuming everything are 64-bit values (which I don't know if they are), a NumPy array would have only five more than that. Note that an array has to hold at least its data type, a pointer to its buffer, an offset, a shape and the strides.

Comment: Make your empty array in **IPython**, and call it `a`. Then type `a.` and a TAB and you can see the strides, shape, flags and things in there.

Comment: @chepner Lol wut, stackoverflow isn't a place to ask questions about source code?

Comment: It's a place to ask about *your* code, not to ask where you can find a copy of another project's source code.

Comment: @chepner so because cpython 3 and numpy aren't *mine* I can't ask questions about them?

Comment: @MarkSetchell some of those are python-methods and abstractions over the type that have nothing to do with the underlying memory layout of the instance.

Comment: Sure, it just needs to be a *focused* question with evidence of research. Have you *looked* at the Numpy source yet?

Comment: @chepner yes, i have... but that's absolutely not required. I could ask this question and it would be totally on topic even if I didn't know C at all. The only thing that matters for this site, is that the question is clearly defined and not a duplicate.

Comment: And yet you are essentially just asking for a pointer to an external resource, namely the location in the source where `numpy.array` is defined. *That* makes this off-topic.

Comment: @chepner no, pasting the source code without linking to it, or explaining the overhead in English both answer the question, which is in the title -- "Why does a numpy array have 96 bytes of overhead?"

Comment: `.__array_interface__` gives a `dict` of (most) of that header content.  So as to why - it needs someplace to store attributes like shape, strides and dtype.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: "96 bytes is 16 64bit ints" No, 12.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtsaysGoFundMonica `$me--`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array is present in C sources in *numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h*

See: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h

Looks like it has several pointers, number of dimensions and PyObject_HEAD, which all may in total count to number of bytes you see.

```c
/*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 * The main array object structure.                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 */
/* This struct will be moved to a private header in a future release */
typedef struct tagPyArrayObject_fields {
    PyObject_HEAD
    /* Pointer to the raw data buffer */
    char *data;
    /* The number of dimensions, also called 'ndim' */
    int nd;
    /* The size in each dimension, also called 'shape' */
    npy_intp *dimensions;
    /*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     * Number of bytes to jump to get to the                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     * next element in each dimension                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     */
    npy_intp *strides;

    PyObject *base;
    /* Pointer to type structure */
    PyArray_Descr *descr;
    /* Flags describing array -- see below */
    int flags;
    /* For weak references */
    PyObject *weakreflist;
} PyArrayObject_fields;
```

Comment: *Every piece of data* in a language like Python is stored in a complex data structure whose internal implementation is of interest only to the writers of the interpreter.  *"It just works.  Like magic..."*  And, the days when we had to care about things like "96 bytes" are long, long gone.  *(Yay!)*

Comment: I don't understand why you're making that point, @MikeRobinson - internals may be irrelevant to you, but that certainly does not mean they are de-facto irrelevant.  96 bytes may not sound like much, but sometimes, it's the difference between good and poor performance.