# Numpy structured array as a class to save memory?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm creating a large number of numpy "structured arrays" (like over a million) with the same dtype (including column names). I assume that if I create them all independently, I'm going to waste memory storing their names and dtypes for each instance. Is there a way to store this information only once, e.g. by creating a class and using the dtype in the class instead of storing it per array instance?

Comment: Create a single 2D structured array and keep a dictionary of row indices? This is very abstract and tough to answer

Comment: If I make the dtype immutable, will the structured arrays simply keep a reference to the dtype, rather than make a copy?

Comment: The size of the dtype is most likely negligible compared to an array of even a few elements. As far as I know, dtype objects are immutable, so I don't think NumPy should make copies of them, but in any case I'm not sure that should be your focus... Each array has more additional storage, like pointers, shape, etc. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60302874/1782792)). As @roganjosh points out, a single array and some additional structure of indices is probably better, but the question is to vague to give more specific advice.

Comment: What's the number of fields of this dtype?  And typical array shape?

Comment: @hpaulj - only 2 fields, an unsigned int and a float. Typical array shape is these 2 fields times perhaps 10 to 100 rows

Comment: You could define `dt = np.dtype([...])`, and use `np.array(..., dtype=dt)` when creating the arrays.  That way all arrays would reference the same `dtype` object.  The memory savings will be, I think, minor.  But your code should be cleaner.